# Populating the mindfulness section in the iOS Health Section

Tags: ios, healthkit

I found the Health app has a mindfulness section, yet I did not find in the documentation how to contribute to that section. Concocting a web search for this requirement returns me a collection of worldwide retreat centers... could you direct me to something meaningful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found `HKCategoryTypeIdentifierMindfulSession`.

> A category sample type for recording a mindful session.

[Apple docs.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkcategorytypeidentifiermindfulsession)

This is iOS 10+ only. I think they created this for the new Breathe app to track how much time you spent meditating. It is awesome, you should use this if you building meditation app or something in this area.

Comment: Thanks, I shall test it along with the information about how to cope with iHealth information. In my case I would like to afmdd this feature to my iPuja meditation timer and so I hope they also have a time quantity for this property especially because counting breaths is perhaps beyond today's sensors...

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci try to use the watchOS 3 Breather app. I haven't used it yet but what I here'd from people it is amazing. it doesn't sensor breathing but it doing something else, I don't remember what.

Comment: Is there available some sample about how to use it?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.1, Xcode 8.2**

Here is the way to mindfull section on healthkit
but before integration keep some point in mind:-
1 - it's only available in ios 10 and onwards
2 - you need to take user permission to access those data
3 - here I am showing how to populate the data in health kit mindfulness section only as per question need

First take user permission
let say we have taken implemented an IBAction in a button

```
//Taking permission from user
@IBAction func activateHealthKit(_ sender: Any) {
    let typestoRead = Set([
        HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.mindfulSession)!
        ])

    let typestoShare = Set([
        HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.mindfulSession)!
        ])

    self.healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: typestoShare, read: typestoRead) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success == false {
            print("solve this error\(error)")
            NSLog(" Display not allowed")
        }
        if success == true {
            print("dont worry everything is good\(success)")
            NSLog(" Integrated SuccessFully")
        }
    }
}
```

> Dont forgot to add privacy option in plist

which goes something like this
  Privacy - Health Share Usage Description
  Privacy - Health Update Usage Description

[image: Xcode info plist]

then save the data to health kit mindfull section

```
func saveMindfullAnalysis() {

    // alarmTime and endTime are NSDate objects
    if let mindfulType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .mindfulSession) {

        // we create our new object we want to push in Health app
        let mindfullSample = HKCategorySample(type:mindfulType, value: 0, start: self.alarmTime, end: self.endTime)

        // at the end, we save it
        healthStore.save(mindfullSample, withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                // something happened
                return
            }

            if success {
                print("My new data was saved in HealthKit")

            } else {
                // something happened again
            }

        })

    }

}
```

here I have taken a simple timer which denotes the user meditation time when user start the time it's started analyzing and then when stop it save the data on health kit mindfull section

full project link on git hub for reference to the beginner's - [Download](https://github.com/abdulKarim002/HealthKit-Mindfulness)

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Mindful Minutes session on HealthKit this way:

Create the Health store:

```
HKHealthStore *healthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];
```

Ask the user for the right permission:

```
NSArray *writeTypes = @[[HKSampleType categoryTypeForIdentifier:HKCategoryTypeIdentifierMindfulSession]];

[healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:writeTypes] readTypes:nil completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         //manage the success or failure case
    }];
```

Write a function to actually save the session:

```
-(void)writeMindfulSessionWithStartTime:(NSDate *)start andEndTime:(NSDate *)end{    
    HKCategoryType *mindfulType = [HKCategoryType categoryTypeForIdentifier:HKCategoryTypeIdentifierMindfulSession];
    HKCategorySample* mindfulSample = [HKCategorySample categorySampleWithType:mindfulType value:0 startDate:start endDate:end];

    [healthStore saveObject:mindfulSample withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Error while saving a mindful session: %@.", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

**EDIT:** Please, pay attention: this feature is only available on iOS 10. If you ask for this permission on iOS 9 (or less) the app will crash.