# How to add mindful minutes to iOS healthkit app in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I'm tyng to create a simple cordova plugin using objective c.

the purpose of this plugin is to add mindful minutes to the ios healthkit via the app.

Now, I found a few tutorials on how to add mindful minutes to the healthkit ap via Swift like this one: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/read-write-mindful-minutes-from-healthkit-with-swift-232b65118fe2/

but I need to do this in objective C... However, I cannot find any tutorials on how to do this!

Could someone please advice on this issue of point me in a right direction?

P.S. I'm a beginner in swift and objective c.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898162/populating-the-mindfulness-section-in-the-ios-health-section) which linked to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategorytypeidentifiermindfulsession?language=objc). Here is the full reference for the [health kit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/data_types?language=objc).

I couldn't find any tutorials but the link points to using the `HKCategoryTypeIdentifierMindfulSession` variable.

Comment: Yes, I have found that myself when i was doing my research.